# using IPython notebook with docker

Tags: linux, docker, vmware, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to docker and IPython notebook, and I have the following question:

I'm using VMware to run linux ubuntu on a windows machine. Inside the VM I have a docker which runs the server/kernel for IPython notebook. Now, I downloaded some files into the linux VM, and I'm trying to access them from the IPython notebook, but I get an error "no such file or directory" (for example when I try to open a file in my home directory on the VM).

I guess I don't understand something very basic about how the docker is related to the host file system and how the IPython notebook is related to its server/kernel.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you run your container?

Comment: the docker run command is this: docker run -p 8888:8888 --name tensorflow-udacity -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow-udacity/assignments:0.5.0

Comment: Docker creates its own filesystem for each container, separate from the host (which in your case is a VM, so it's two levels removed from your Windows file system). You can bind mount a container with the `-v` option to `docker run`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume